# what is the URL for my servlet.war?

Tags: java, deployment, servlets, jboss

Hey , I am new to servlet and jboss, I just deploy my servlet on jboss 4.2 .jboss console shows me it is deployed successfully

my web.xml contain

```
<display-name>Notification_Auth_server_simulator</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
   <description></description>
   <display-name>Notify</display-name>
  <servlet-name>Notify</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.me.Notify</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Notify</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/notify</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
  </web-app>
```

and for jboss-web.xml

```
  <jboss-web>
  <context-root>mysite</context-root>
  </jboss-web>
```

I tried in my browser
  http://localhost:8080/mysite/notify   and it doesn't work

what is the correct site name ?

Thanks

Comment: show your servlet code, and the logs

Comment: so, ultimately, what do you try in the browser - the original version with \, or the one after the update?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work. That's why you're here :) But what happens instead? What error page/code/message did you got? Doesn't the server logs tell something interesting?

Comment: one after update, it doesn't connect

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense with the required fixes made to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The slashes are the other way around, and there is a double-slash after the colon:

```
http://localhost:8080/mysite/notify
```

Furthermore, if your servlet doesn't support the `GET` http method, it won't work. You have to override the `doGet()` method.

Also make sure `mysite` is the name of your war.

Comment: did you note the other two things?

Comment: After three years, Thanks A lot :)

Answer (score 1):

> it doesn't connect

Possible causes:

1. The server isn't started.
2. The server has shut down itself due to a fatal failure during startup.
3. The hostname/IP is unknown.
4. The port number is wrong.

Possible solutions:

1. Start the server.
2. Read server logs for any failures and fix accordingly.
3. Verify correctness of hostname and IP. Use `ping` to check if it responds. Try using IP address instead of hostname e.g. `http://127.0.0.1:8080` (if that works, then `hosts` file is bogus).
4. Verify correctness of port number. It's configureable in server settings. Use `tracert` to check if it exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably attach to running JBoss via JMX and read what are the real runtime setting of your application. Use jconsole for that, connecting to local process needs no configuration.